# How is the quantum effective action defined in a theory with more than one field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, action, 1pi-effective-action, functional-determinants

How is the one-loop quantum effective action derived in a theory with more than one interacting field? When looking at some books and my course notes I find that the expression for the one-loop quantum effective action in a scalar theory can be computed as:

$$\Gamma^{\text{(1-loop)}}[\phi_c] = S[\phi_c] + \frac{i\hbar}{2}\ln{\det\left(\frac{\delta^2 S[\phi]}{\delta \phi\delta\phi}\right)_{\phi_c}}\tag{1}$$

where $S[\phi_c]$ is the classical action. This determinant comes from a expansion in the action that allow you to write it like a gaussian integral. However, the theory I am working with has two interacting fields (one real scalar and one complex scalar). Since my action have a term of the form $\lambda \phi \varphi^\dagger\varphi$ I don't know how to compute the one-loop quantum effective action.

Any tips or resources where I can read about this? Every book uses the example of a $\phi^n$ theory but I haven't seen one where they put an example with two different fields.

Comment: Since you have a $\varphi^\dagger \varphi$, maybe you can use the path integral over $\mathcal{D}[\varphi^\dagger,\varphi]$ to have a determinant of $\sim(\square+\lambda \phi)$. The associated Hurwitz zeta-regularized determinant will be quadratic in $\lambda \phi$, then do the integral over $\phi$.

Comment: At least formally, you can just replace the second derivative of $S$ with a *Hessian matrix* $\frac{\delta^2 S}{\delta \phi_a \delta \phi_b}$, where $a, b$ are indices that run over the different fields.

Comment: I tried using the Hessian but I did not get anything similar to the 1PI Feynman diagrams that are expected to be correct.

Comment: Consider to list the full action for clarity.